# Regex: return the first line after the matching line

Tags: regex, grep

How do I return the first line after the matching line? I realize different regex engines vary; I'm interested particularly in the `grep` version.

Answer (score 3):

There is a straightforward way to do this using grep.

```
grep -A1 'PATTERN' file
```

The [`-A`](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) option means print **NUM** lines of trailing context after matching lines.

```
grep -A1 'PATTERN' file | grep -v 'PATTERN'
```

The [`-v`](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) option inverts the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. You can use this option if you only want the line after the matched pattern to be printed.

Comment: This is wrong, OP request `How do I return the first line after the matching line` and this gives both the line with pattern and the next line.

Comment: Actually OP did not specifically say if he/she wanted the matching line also.. FYI

Answer (score 1):

actually, you can do it quite easily with two grep invocations:

```
grep --no-group-separator -A1 pattern input.dat | grep -v pattern
```

but this is a bit ugly because you have to enter the pattern twice, and this can be error prone. You could wrap it with a script, but personally, I tend to use sed for this sort of thing.

Anyway, here's an example:

```
[lineafter.sed $] cat input.dat
aaa0
bbb0
ccc0
ddd0
eee0
fff0
ggg0
hhh0
aaa1
bbb1
ccc1
ddd1
eee1
fff1
ggg1
hhh1
[lineafter.sed $] grep --no-group-separator -A1  ccc input.dat | grep -v ccc
ddd0
ddd1
[mnoy@mn09 lineafter.sed $]
```

(note that if you don't use --no-group-separator, you'll end up with -- markers to delimit the instances of the match (which might be what you want...)).

Comment: This won't print anything if `pattern` is present in the second line.

Comment: But well, for that case it would help to play a little bit with `-w` option of `grep`. `grep -vw pattern` will make it unless both lines are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
sed '/pattern/,+1!d' filename
```

Comment: This is wrong, OP request `How do I return the first line after the matching line` and this gives both the line with pattern and the next line.

Answer (score 0):

This will only give the next line after `pattern` found

```
awk 'f {print;f=0} /pattern/ {f=1}' file
```

example

```
cat file
one
two
three
four
```

```
awk 'f {print;f=0} /two/ {f=1}' file
three
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with grep, but it's very easy with sed:

```
sed -n '/pattern/{n;p}' input.dat
```

example:

```
[lineafter.sed $] cat input.dat
aaa0
bbb0
ccc0
ddd0
eee0
fff0
ggg0
hhh0
aaa1
bbb1
ccc1
ddd1
eee1
fff1
ggg1
hhh1
[lineafter.sed $]
[lineafter.sed $] sed -n '/ccc/{n;p}' input.dat
ddd0
ddd1
[lineafter.sed $]
```